# Setting a protobuf item's value replaces a previously set variable as well

Tags: c++, windows, protocol-buffers

I have created a simple Protobuf based config file and have been using it without any issues until now. The issue is that I added two new items to my settings (`Config.proto`) and now whatever value I set for the last variable is reflected in the previous one.

The following snapshot demonstrates this better. As you can see below, the value of `fv_shape_predictor_path` and `fv_eyenet_path` depend solely on order of being set.  the one that is set last changes the others value.

[image]

I made sure the cpp files related to `Config.proto` are built afresh. I also tested this under Linux and there it works just fine. It seems its only happening in windows! it also doesn't affect any other items in the same settings. its just these two new ones.

I have no idea what is causing this or how to go about it. For reference this is how the protobuf looks like:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package FVConfig;

message Config {

    FV Configuration = 4 ;
    
    message FAN_MODELS_WEIGHTS{
        string fan_2DFAN_4 =  1; 
        string fan_3DFAN_4 =  2; 
        string fan_depth   =  3; 
    }
    
    message S3FD_MODELS_WEIGHTS{
        string s3fd = 1; 
    }
  
    message DLIB_MODELS_WEIGHTS{
        string dlib_default = 1; 
    }
     
    message MTCNN_MODELS_WEIGHTS {
        string mt_onet = 1; 
        string mt_pnet = 2; 
        string mt_rnet = 3; 
    }

    message FV_MODEL_WEIGHTS {
        string r18 = 1; 
        string r50 = 2; 
        string r101 = 3;
        repeated ModelContainer new_models_weights = 4;

        message ModelContainer{
            string model_name = 1;
            string model_weight_path = 2;
            string description = 3;
        }
    }

    message FV {
        MTCNNDetectorSettings mtcnn = 1 ;
        FaceVerificationSettings fv = 2 ;
  }

    message MTCNNDetectorSettings {

        Settings settings = 1;
        MTCNN_MODELS_WEIGHTS model_weights = 4;
        
        message Settings {
            string mt_device            = 2;
            int32 mt_webcam_source      = 100;
            int32 mt_upper_threshold    = 600; 
            int32 mt_hop                = 700; 
        }
    }

    message FaceVerificationSettings {

        Settings settings = 1;
        FV_MODEL_WEIGHTS model_weights = 2;
        
        message Settings {
            string fv_model_name = 1; 
            
            string fv_model_checkpoint_path = 2; 
            bool fv_rebuild_cache   = 3;
            
            bool fv_short_circut    = 6;
            bool fv_accumulate_score = 7;
            
            string fv_config_file_path = 10;
            string fv_img_bank_folder_root = 11;
            string fv_cache_folder = 12;
            string fv_postfix       = 13;
            string fv_device        = 14;

            int32 fv_idle_interval = 15; 
            bool fv_show_dbg_info = 16;
            
            // these are the new ones
            string fv_shape_predictor_path = 17;
            string fv_eyenet_path = 18;
            }
    }

} //end of Config message
```

What am I missing here? How should I be going about this? Restarting Windows and Visual Studio didn't do any good either. I'm using protobuf `3.11.4` both on Linux and Windows.

Comment: [example] please

Comment: I'll try to comeup with something but its hard becasue I cant repreduce this on linux. so its not something obvious at least to me. I need some starting points to know where this is stemming from.

Comment: If making a dummy `main` doesn't work for an MRE, then try cutting away swathes of the current program until it does work? protobufs are one of those things that you expect to "just work" so I can understand the frustration.

Comment: Just to be sure: you're using the Windows protoc to generate the code compiled for Windows right? https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.11.4

Comment: @JohnFilleau I'll try my best and see how it goes. thanks. 
and yes thats it I'm using the prebuilt binaries for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to only exist in the Windows version of `Protobuf` `3.11.4` (didn't test with any newer version though).

Basically what happened was that I use to first create a Config object and initialize it with some default values. When I added these two entries to my Config.proto, I forgot to also add an initialization entry like other entries, thinking I'm fine with the default (which I assumed would be `""`).

This doesn't pose any issues under `Linux`/`G++` and the program builds and runs just fine and works as intended. However under Windows this results in the behavior you just witnessed i.e. setting any of those newly added entries, would also set the other entries values. So basically I either had to create a whole new `Config` object or had to explicitly set their values when using the `load_default_config`.

To be more concrete this is the snippet I used for setting some default values in my `Protobuf` configs.

These reside in a separate header called `Utility.h`:

```cpp
   inline FVConfig::Config load_default_config()
    {
        FVConfig::Config baseCfg;
        auto config = baseCfg.mutable_configuration();
        load_fv_default_settings(config->mutable_fv());
        load_mtcnn_default_settings(config->mutable_mtcnn());
        return baseCfg;
    }

    inline void load_fv_default_settings(FVConfig::Config_FaceVerificationSettings* fv)
    {
        fv->mutable_settings()->set_fv_config_file_path(fv::config_file_path);
        fv->mutable_settings()->set_fv_device(fv::device);
        fv->mutable_settings()->set_fv_rebuild_cache(fv::rebuild_cache);
        ...

        // these two lines were missing previously and to my surprise, this was indeed
        // the cause of the weird behavior.  
        fv->mutable_settings()->set_fv_shape_predictor_path(fv::shape_predictor_path);
        fv->mutable_settings()->set_fv_eyenet_path(fv::eyenet_path);

        auto new_model_list = fv->mutable_model_weights()->mutable_new_models_weights()->Add();
        new_model_list->set_model_name("r18");
        new_model_list->set_description("default");
        new_model_list->set_model_weight_path(fv::model_weights_r18);
    }

    inline void load_mtcnn_default_settings(FVConfig::Config_MTCNNDetectorSettings* mt)
    {
        mt->mutable_settings()->set_mt_device(mtcnn::device);
        mt->mutable_settings()->set_mt_hop(mtcnn::hop);
        ....
    }
```

Not sure this counts as a bug in `Protobuf`, or my wrong approach here.